# ARIMA model with non-normal error

Tags: r, time-series, normal-distribution

I'm fitting `ARIMA(0,0,1)` model in `R` with one exogenous variable.

After fitting, I tested the error term and it's highly non-normal (it's like `t-distributed` error):
[image]

My question is: is there any package in `R` that can fit `ARIMA` model with `t-distributed` error? Or it there any other remedy to this problem?

The data is log-transformed data already so I guess I cannot perform another data transformation.

Thank you for your help in advance!

---

Here is the data:

```
dput(x)
c(1.098612289, 0, 1.791759469, 1.386294361, 0, 2.079441542, 2.772588722, 
2.564949357, 3.737669618, 3.761200116, 3.891820298, 3.555348061, 
2.944438979, 2.772588722, 1.791759469, 2.772588722, 2.564949357, 
3.258096538, 3.295836866, 2.890371758, 2.772588722, 2.197224577, 
4.077537444, 4.828313737, 5.855071922, 6.620073207, 7.561641746, 
7.887208586, 7.557472902, 6.747586527, 5.583496309, 4.465908119, 
3.526360525, 2.890371758, 2.564949357, 2.397895273, 2.302585093, 
0.693147181, 1.386294361, 0.693147181, 0.693147181, 0, 0, 1.098612289, 
0.693147181, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.693147181, 0.693147181, 0, 
0, 0.693147181, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.693147181, 0, 0.693147181, 0.693147181, 1.386294361, 
0.693147181, 1.098612289, 2.564949357, 3.555348061, 4.744932128, 
4.615120517, 4.934473933, 4.779123493, 5.308267697, 5.303304908, 
5.416100402, 5.379897354, 5.153291594, 5.081404365, 4.927253685, 
4.86753445, 4.356708827, 4.060443011, 3.891820298, 3.091042453, 
3.091042453, 2.995732274, 2.302585093, 2.079441542, 1.609437912, 
0.693147181, 0, 0)

dput(y)
c(-2.760818612, -0.969058209, -1.374522756, -2.760817117, -0.681374268, 
0.011775716, -0.195861406, 0.976866516, 1.000404862, 1.131034014, 
0.794568131, 0.183662413, 0.011814959, -0.96901336, 0.011818696, 
-0.195818426, 0.497333426, 0.535078613, 0.129616682, 0.01183645, 
-0.5635262, 1.316797505, 2.067596972, 3.094420195, 3.859561475, 
4.801489346, 5.127554079, 4.798176537, 3.988449441, 2.824408827, 
1.706836735, 0.767295318, 0.131309734, -0.19411042, -0.361162633, 
-0.456471128, -2.065908853, -1.372761111, -2.065908104, -2.065907917, 
-2.759055098, -2.759055098, -1.660442435, -2.065907356, -2.759054536, 
-2.759054536, -2.759054536, -2.759054536, -2.759054536, -2.759054536, 
-2.759054536, -2.065907168, -2.065906981, -2.759054162, -2.759054162, 
-2.065906794, -2.759053975, -2.759053975, -2.759053975, -2.759053975, 
-2.759053975, -2.759053975, -2.759053975, -2.759053975, -2.759053975, 
-2.759053975, -2.759053975, -2.759053975, -2.759053975, -2.759053975, 
-2.759053975, -2.759053975, -2.759053975, -2.759053975, -2.065906607, 
-2.759053787, -2.06590642, -2.065906232, -1.37275849, -2.065905484, 
-1.660440001, -0.194100686, 0.796304383, 1.985909791, 1.856116899, 
2.17549615, 2.020167801, 2.549349637, 2.544424292, 2.657261726, 
2.621099122, 2.394525569, 2.3226683, 2.168543275, 2.108848197, 
1.598036993, 1.301781851, 1.133168127, 0.332394215, 0.332398148, 
0.237091526, -0.456053969, -0.679196209, -1.149199089, -2.065489634, 
-2.758636814, -2.758636814, -2.758636814)
```

And my code:

```
y1 = y
x_data1 = matrix(c(x), ncol = 1)
ts_mod1 = arima(y1, order = c(0,0,1), xreg = x_data1)
ts_res1 = ts_mod1$residuals

qqnorm(ts_res1, main = "", cex.axis = 1.2, cex.lab = 1.45)
qqline(ts_res1, col = "red")
```

Comment: Please share the data so that it becomes easier to replicate your probelm and help. Use dput to give us the structure of the data and values. It seems to me that this data has high heteroskedasticity.

Answer (score 0):

This q-q plot is indicative of a [heavy - tailed distribution](http://emp.byui.edu/BrownD/Stats-intro/dscrptv/graphs/qq-plot_egs.htm). You can refer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101274/how-to-interpret-a-qq-plot) to understand the various types of q-q plots.
To answer your question there are packages that do a better job of dealing with non-normal distributions. Try the `forecast` package -

```
require('forecast')
ts_mod1 <- auto.arima(y1,xreg = x_data1)
ts_mod1

# Series: y1 
# ARIMA(4,0,2) with non-zero mean 
# 
# Coefficients:
#     ar1      ar2     ar3      ar4      ma1     ma2  intercept  x_data1
# 0.7269  -0.3027  0.2060  -0.0391  -0.6260  0.4672    -2.4920   0.8695
# s.e.  0.4409   0.4004  0.1771   0.1796   0.4577  0.3664     0.2536   0.1102
# 
# sigma^2 estimated as 0.3996:  log likelihood=-99.8
# AIC=217.6   AICc=219.44   BIC=241.74
```

Here `auto.arima` automatically selects the best `ARIMA(4,0,2)` model based on the `AIC` value which is better than the `ARIMA(0,0,1)` with `AIC = 219.96`.
The fit is better too as shown by this q-q plot -

[image: Q-Q plot for ARIMA(4,0,2)]

Comment: Thank you. But I must use this model setting. There are some economic meaning behind the model...

Comment: The model's variables are mostly not statistically significant and the errors have a nonconstant variance when you plot the residuals

Answer (score 0):

There is another package in R called Autobox.  It is available from autobox.com(I am affiliated with it).

The standardized plot shows that X is related to Y.[image: Normalized Bivariated Scatterplot]

Model with differencing, the x variable and 3 outliers. Note the .257 coefficient is much lower.

[image: Model with differencing]

By testing for variance change and using Weighted Least Squares(GLM) we have identified a change in the variance beginning at period 44.  See the paper [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/for.3980070102/abstract).

[image: Tsay variance test]

Residuals[image: Residuals]